# How to link a button in ViewController.swift to an xib file?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, xib

I want to create a button in my view controller that links to a xib file screen. What lines of code do I need to write in the IBAction in my ViewController.swift file?

I have tried writing code that is used to connect two storyboard files together but it doesn't seem to work.

This is an example of code that I use to connect to a storyboard file but what code do I use for an xib file:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let progressVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProgressVC") as! WGProgressVC.progressVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(progressVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want to connect my Main.storyboard file to a xib file but it is not working since I don't know the lines of code I need to write. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this:

```
@IBDesignable class MyBtn: UIButton {
    // any outlets here
    // @IBOutlet ...

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initNib()
    }

    func initNib() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: MyBtn.self)
        bundle.loadNibNamed("MyBtnXib", owner: self, options: nil)
        // any customization below
        ...
    }
}
```

In general it's good to use `IBDesignable` for your UI elements and `IBInspectable` for reasonable variables if you use IB.